# Android sensors stop working after sleep -> how to restart them?

Tags: android, service, android-sensors, restart

this may be a little off topic for stackoverflow and I apologize for that. But nobody in the android boards seems to be able to help. The best people are at stackoverflow, So I decided to try my luck here.

My Lenovo Yoga book has the annoying problem of loosing sensors(1) after sleep/stand by. This can happen after seconds or after hours. Only a restart of the tablet brings them back. Apparently, other users(2) are suffering from the same problem, but so far no solution has been found.

Is there any way to restart the sensors without having to reboot the device? What service is responsible for controlling the sensors, is it sensorservice (android.gui.SensorServer)?

It sounds like a simple problem (probably isn't). But I find absolutely nothing on it in the internet, which makes it all the more frustrating.

Thanks very much for any help!

Best regards - Pesche

(1) Accelerometer (including auto rotation), light, magnetic field, orientation and GPS

(2) See lenovo forums: "Halo Keyboard doesn't wake up"